# persistent install or upgrade errors - "files list file for package 'libinput-bin' is missing final newline"

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

System Ubuntu server 20.04.3, Raspberry pi 4B.
Attempts to run apt install, apt upgrade, virtually anything returns the same errors:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
  files list file for package 'libinput-bin' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

The name of the file may change when attempting to install different packages but the errors persist no matter what I try to install.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove problematic file by

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libinput-bin.list
```

and then reinstall this package to get correct contents of the above file by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libinput-bin
```

Comment: dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libinput-bin' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libdbus-glib-1-2:armhf' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Comment: @rpmckinley the warning will go away when you can do the reinstallation, and will not stop `dpkg` from running. You'll have to remove the file that the new error is about and reinstall that package to restore it as well. What happened to your dpkg info???

Comment: Fatal errors in dpkg have NOT been resolved. Please do not delete my questions until they have been resolved.

Comment: @rpmckinley I know you haven't resolved it. The message about the `libinput-bin` file list is a warning which will go away when you follow the second step in N0rbert's answer, but you cannot follow the second step because you have a new error about another package's file list, so you have to apply N0rbert's first command to that file list as well (delete the broken file list) and then apply the second command to both of the packages whose file lists have been removed. But perhaps another file list will turn out to be broken, in which case, I am wondering how this happened.